# Evaluating product of converging a diverging term

Tags: python, function, numpy, scipy, nan

I want to evaluate the following expression numerically in Python

exp((x^2))*Erfc(x).

where Erfc denotes the complementary error function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Complementary_error_function). Erfc(x) is available from Scipy Special. Even though for large x, $exp(x^2)$ diverges, the product has a finite value. To be exact

Lim x->\infinity exp((x^2))*Erfc(x) = 1/(sqrt(Pi) * x).

Unfortunately, Python doesn't evaluate this expression and gives me back NaN for large values of x. Is there any way to implement this function such that for large x, the Python still produces the correct answer? (My code and output is given below.)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy 
from scipy import special as spl

def my_fun(x):

    return np.exp(x**2)*spl.erfc(x);


print (my_fun(10))

print (my_fun(50))

print (my_fun(100))

0.05614099274382259

    Warning (from warnings module):
      File "/Users/spjoy/Working/Projects/Wigner Crystal/Python/num_eval.py", line 7
        return np.exp(x**2)*spl.erfc(x);
    RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
    
    Warning (from warnings module):
      File "/Users/spjoy/Working/Projects/Wigner Crystal/Python/num_eval.py", line 7
        return np.exp(x**2)*spl.erfc(x);
    RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
    nan
    nan
```

Comment: can you show us your Python code and the tests you have done.

Comment: I have added the code and output in my updated question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SciPy has an implementation of that function: [`scipy.special.erfcx`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfcx.html).

E.g.

```
In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]: from scipy.special import erfcx, erfc
```

A moderate value, where `exp(x**2)*erfc(x)` doesn't suffer from overflow and underflow, to verify that we get the same result with `erfcx(x)`:

```
In [10]: x = 2.5

In [11]: np.exp(x**2) * erfc(x)
Out[11]: 0.21080636406114353

In [12]: erfcx(x)
Out[12]: 0.2108063640611436
```

A big value of `x`, where `exp(x**2)` overflows, but `erfcx(x)` gives a result:

```
In [13]: x = 50.0

In [14]: np.exp(x**2) * erfc(x)
<ipython-input-14-bb75732dec2d>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  np.exp(x**2) * erfc(x)
<ipython-input-14-bb75732dec2d>:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  np.exp(x**2) * erfc(x)
Out[14]: nan

In [15]: erfcx(x)
Out[15]: 0.011281536265323772

In [16]: 1/(np.sqrt(np.pi)*x)  # Verify the asymptotic approximation.
Out[16]: 0.011283791670955126
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great. I am actually curious how does Scipy implements the function "erfcx".

Comment: The SciPy function is a wrapper of a C++ implementation in [Faddeeva.cc](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/701ffcc8a6f04509d115aac5e5681c538b5265a2/scipy/special/Faddeeva.cc).